# Ввод данных с клавиатуры

Tags: macos, objective-c, xcode

Я новичок в  Objective-C. Мне необходимо ввести данные с клавиатуры в переменные *а* и *b*, а затем вывести сумму. Как это реализовать на Objective-C? В *С++* я это делал так:

```
cin >> a >> b;
a+=b;
cout << a;
```

Comment: Вы консольную программу пишете?

Comment: Да - программа для консоли.

Comment: Я забыл, что Objective-C поддерживает С, а значит тут можно использовать scanf и printf.

Comment: Да )) именно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

@autoreleasepool {

    char buffer[255];
    memset (buffer, 0, 255);  //this line isn't required, I just like having my
                                        //array zeroed out prior to use.
    NSLog(@"Enter your name:");
    if (scanf("%254[0-9a-zA-Z ]", buffer) == 1) {
      if ([@"Bob" isEqualToString: @(buffer)]) {
         NSLog(@"Hello Bob");
      } else if ([@"Joe" isEqualToString: @(buffer)]) {
        NSLog(@"Hello Joe");
      } else {
        NSLog(@"I don't know you.");
      }
    }

}

return 0;
}
```